# Radio button and checkbox

Tags: angular

I am working on angular. I have 3 radio buttons coming dynamically: full, none, partial. when I click on partial radio btn it opens list of child in it with checkbox coming dynamically.

I have made one array in which radio btn and checkbox value which are selected will be forwarded after submit click.
If user selects full then the value of radio btn should be added in that array same way if user selects partial then only checkbox value should be sent in that array

But in my case if I select radio btn full then click on partial selecting randomly any checkbox and then submitting so it is taking value of full radio btn as well.
I tried just adding array=[] empty array onclick of radio btn but it is removing all elements when second record full or none is selected

Also the value of one record like full or none or partial (value of checkbox) it should be the final value no repetition of value in that array.
Data should not be redundant.

Comment: I gave up in line 3. Use punctuation and paragraphs.

Comment: Could you share the code you are working on? THat might help in getting your issue fixed...